# Why does Xcode crash when I try to add a UIPageViewController view to the main view?

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, uiviewcontroller, uipageviewcontroller

I'm following this tutorial to create a UIPageViewController:
[appcoda UIPageViewController tutorial](http://www.appcoda.com/uipageviewcontroller-storyboard-tutorial/)

However, the only difference in the code is I am using only 1 UIViewController and 1 UIPageViewController instead of 2 UIViewControllers and 1 UIPageViewController, and I've modified the code to allow me to accomplish this.

However, Xcode seems to crash in viewDidLoad in the code:

```
[self.view addSubview:_pageViewController.view];
```

Here is my code:

.h

```
@property (strong, nonatomic) UIPageViewController *pageViewController;
@property (strong, nonatomic) NSArray *pageImages;

@property (nonatomic) NSUInteger pageIndex;
@property (nonatomic) NSString *titleText;
@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIImageView *imageFile;
```

.m

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.

    // Override point for customization after application launch.
    UIPageControl *pageControl = [UIPageControl appearance];
    pageControl.pageIndicatorTintColor = [UIColor lightGrayColor];
    pageControl.currentPageIndicatorTintColor = [UIColor blackColor];
    pageControl.backgroundColor = [UIColor whiteColor];

    self.pageImages = @[@"page1.png", @"page2.png", @"page3.png", @"page4.png"];

    // Create page view controller
    self.pageViewController = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"PageViewController"];
    self.pageViewController.dataSource = self;

    NSArray *viewControllers = @[ [self viewControllerAtIndex:0] ];
    [self.pageViewController setViewControllers:viewControllers direction:UIPageViewControllerNavigationDirectionForward animated:NO completion:nil];

    // Change the size of page view controller
    self.pageViewController.view.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, self.view.frame.size.width, self.view.frame.size.height - 30);

  //     [self addChildViewController:_pageViewController];
    [self.view addSubview:_pageViewController.view];
    //   [self.pageViewController didMoveToParentViewController:self];
}

- (id )viewControllerAtIndex:(NSUInteger)index
{

    if ( ([self.pageImages count] == 0) || (index >= [self.pageImages count]) )
    {
        return nil;
    }

    self.imageFile = self.pageImages[index];

    self.pageIndex = index;

    return self;
}

#pragma mark - Page View Controller Data Source

- (UIViewController *)pageViewController:(UIPageViewController *)pageViewController viewControllerBeforeViewController:(UIViewController *)viewController
{
    NSUInteger index = self.pageIndex;

    if ((index == 0) || (index == NSNotFound)) {
        return nil;
    }

    index--;
    return [self viewControllerAtIndex:index];
}

- (UIViewController *)pageViewController:(UIPageViewController *)pageViewController viewControllerAfterViewController:(UIViewController *)viewController
{
    NSUInteger index = self.pageIndex;

    if (index == NSNotFound)
    {
        return nil;
    }

    index++;
    if (index == [self.pageImages count])
    {
        return nil;
    }
    return [self viewControllerAtIndex:index];
}

- (NSInteger)presentationCountForPageViewController:(UIPageViewController *)pageViewController
{
    return [self.pageImages count];
}

- (NSInteger)presentationIndexForPageViewController:(UIPageViewController *)pageViewController
{
    return 0;
}
```

I don't quite understand why it's crashing. Thanks for your help!

Comment: can you put breakpoint and tell us on which line it is crashing? or what error you get?

Comment: Xcode is crashing??  That's bad.

Comment: @ChintaN: look at my description, the crash occurs in viewDidLoad.

Comment: @Varosion: the storyboard ID for the UIPageViewController has been filled in Storyboard

Comment: @Pangu in viewDidLoad there are couple of lines. you should add debug and try to trace where it crash.